# React image mapper / area subdivision

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image

Hi i Have a Task in which i have to make the map of Slovenia interactive in such a way that when hovered over a statistical area of Slovenia it would make a popup window (tooltip) with the basic information such a name... (and change color slightly), and also i need to make it so that when user clicks on a statistical area it would redirect to a page with more detailed information. also the map size must be responsive based on screen size. So mainly my question is what library to use or any advice how to go about this?

img:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggrWk.png)

i looked at some solutions such as
http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@overlapmedia/imagemapper

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.